# Model description in django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to put a model description or description on the list display page of a certain model in django-admin?

I'm talking about something like when you click a model name link on the homepage of django-admin and when you go to the list display page of that model. There will be a description written on top of the table. Something like

"This model is used to log all accounts that will be fetched by our scrape.... And so on"

Something like that, is it possible?

Comment: Did any of the below answers worked for your case?

Comment: Yes it is, I did some few changes on the HTML side though. Just put the templatetag in a different line just to make sure the button alignments on the right side won't be affected. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would be a very nice feature to be added in the core of Django's admin. Until then here's a quick walkthrough to your question.

Let's assume that you want to print the `docstring` of each model, like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    """
    I wanna get printed in the Admin!
    """

    # model fields here
```

So, you want to print it in the [`change_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) page. Good.

1. Create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) (either within your app or create another app that will hold the *global template tags/filters*) like this:

   ```
   from django import template
   from django.utils.html import mark_safe

   register = template.Library()

   @register.simple_tag()
   def model_desc(obj):
       if obj.__doc__:
           return mark_safe('<p>{}</p>'.format(obj.__doc__))
       return ''
   ```
2. Now, inside your project directory (where `manage.py` lives) create a structure like this:

   ```
   project/
       project/
           project stuff here, i.e wsgi.py, settings etc
       myapp/
           myapp stuff here, i.e models, views etc
       templates/
           admin/
               change_list.html
       manage.py
   ```
3. Inside the `change_list.html` add these:

   ```
   {% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
   {% load yourapp_tags %}

   {# block.super will print the "Select <Model> to change" h1 title #}
   {# The model_desc template tag is the one you created and prints the docstring of the given model #}
   {% block content_title %}{{ block.super }}<br>{% model_desc cl.model %}{% endblock %}
   ```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Model docstring in Django admin]

**[UPDATE]**: I have [seen in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L342-L343) that when there is no `docstring` specified, Django will generate one for you in the following form: `ModelName(model_field_name1, model_field_name2, ...)`. If you do not want that, simply do this:

```
class MyModelWithoutDocstring(models.Model):

    # model fields here

MyModelWithoutDocstring.__doc__ = ''  # "reset" the __doc__ on this model.
```

Comment: In the step 2, you are asking user to create a global change_list.html. But each model will have its own change_list.html. You might want to correct that.

Comment: It depends on how modular you want it to be. I decided to add it globally for all models to expose their `docstring` in the `change_list` page.